# $L_1$ is regular and $L_2$ is not. What can i say about their union or intersection?

Tags: regular-language

Given $L_1$ is a regular language and $L_2$ is a non-regular language.
$\Longrightarrow$ then $L_1\cap L_2$ (the intersection) is non-regular  OR  $L_1\cup L_2$ (the union) is non-regular.

Is it true or false?
Can you give an example/proof?

Comment: What have you try so far? *hint* assume both are regular and try some of the operations that preserve regularity.

Comment: got it! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that $L_2 = (L_1 \cup L_2) \cap \bigl(L_1^c \cup (L_1 \cap L_2)\bigr)$.

Comment: Great! I think i got it!
L2 is non-regular, so it can't be that both the intersection AND the union are regular, because it'll turn L2 into regular (union&intersect between regular languages), in the contrary to our assumption.

thanks:)

Comment: Your argument is almost complete, but don't forget to say something about $L_1^c$. By the way, if you are satisfied with the answer, the usual way to say "thanks" is to accept it.

Comment: If $L$ is regular, then $L^c$ is regular too, for any regular language $L$. I've already proved it (not here) so i took it as obvious.
and i accept your answer.

Comment: See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how to accept an answer.

Comment: oh now i get you.. so i just did it